# asyncio with persistent connections

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

*Disclaimer: This is probably a very basic question, but I just don't understand the concept and am thus unable to achieve what I want.*

I'm trying to implement the basic echo client server using asyncio. I started with the samples included in the documentation.

What I want to achieve is a persistent connection where the client can at any time **other than immediate connection_made** send some data to the server and then read the response (if there is any). The connection must stay open on both ends until explicitly closed.

I'm doing this with protocols sample. Reading other questions / documentation, it seems I could implement this using `loop.call_later()`, but is this really a good solution? Ideally I'd want to use a `Queue` to be able to respond to new packets instantaneously.

I ended up with this code, called from ´MyProtocol.**init**`:

```
    @asyncio.coroutine
    def writer():
        global out_queue
        while True:
            packt = yield from out_queue.get()
            print("yeahhh packet yummy")
            data = bytes(packt.to_json(), 'ascii')
            self.transport.write(data)

    asyncio.async(writer())
```

But this does nothing. I would assume that this would print out the message immediately when a new item is inserted from main client code. Nothing happens...

Further debugging shows that queue is being filled up, but the out_queue.get() coroutine never returns. Initially the out_queue.put even puts the item pretty much directly into the waiter for the initial .get() call, but it's as if the loop wasn't running. It's the same loop used for the entire client connection (i created a new one because I placed everything into a thread). I have checked and the appropriate calls made from .put() call are all for this loop.

Oh, just in case it matters: I'm running this on python 3.3 with asyncio install by pip.

Update: this is how I try to insert items into the queue:

```
def send_packet(loop, queue, packet):
    # this runs in main thread, not the loop thread

    def f():
        print("putting packet into queue")
        queue.put_nowait(packet)  # MUST NOT use .put() as it's a coroutine

    loop.call_soon_threadsafe(f)
    # !!! next one doesn't work !!!
    # loop.call_soon_threadsafe(any_normal_function_with_coroutine_calls())
```

The `print` never executes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason why queue.get() never wakes up after queue.put() is: you create queue with implicit loop (and maybe wait for items from this loop) but push data using another loop instance.

Comment: Well, actually I push them from another thread. But I also tried to push them from a function that was added with `loop.call_soon_threadsafe()', but that function doesn't get called at all.

Comment: NVM, documentation isn't particulary clear on HOW to use the call_soon_threadsafe. I assumed any old function is OK, but it turns out that it's not... Question updated with proper solution

Comment: call_soon, call_later and call_soon_threadsafe accept regular function, not coroutine. Fresh asyncio has checks for it.

Comment: yes, they do, and the checks are there. but it cannot be any old function. it MUST be asyncio.async or similar.

Comment: No, it CAN be any function. 
But if you pass generator function (one with `yield` or `yield from` inside) asyncio will not unwind (unyield) that generator and code will not executed. `asyncio.async` creates `asyncio.Task` that does generator unwinding.

Comment: You are right. However, the function provided MUST NOT use any coroutines anywhere. As soon as yield from is used anywhere in the call stack, the function won't execute. Edit: interesting, removing async() wrapping sped up my code 33%.

Comment: That's how task unwinding works: it schedules execution of next slice from yield to next yield to `loop.call_soon`.
`.call_soon` need next loop iteration with ask for socket polling (maybe instant and very quick, but it's syscall anyway) for execution.